# IOS/Objective-C: Best Practice for Order of Saving and Synching data to server from mobile

Tags: ios, core-data, synchronization, server

there has been a lot written on synching.  However, an important point I have not found much insight into is the order of saving.

Case I.  Have connectivity:

Should you save first to core data and then synch to server...or

Save first to core data and simultaneously or immediately afterwards save to server.... or

Save directly to server using web view and then synch back to phone/core-data.

Case II. No connectivity

Here I think you save to Core Data and the synch upon getting connectivity but would appreciate confirmation.

Comment: There is great variety of the client-server architecture implementations. Each specific case should be considered separately and it's difficult to have a single rule that will be correct everywhere. So please specify how your system components interacts with each other. What kind of information your want to synchronize? How important this information?

Comment: If it's general question, save to device first, connection less stable and requires more time to transmit and save. So the chance to loose higher. Concurrent work could be dangerous in case of fail. It's hard to recognize where data is stored properly. Atomic transactions are more reliable behavior in common.